# Why performing the env command I obtain different values of the environment variables declared into "/etc/environment"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, environment-variables, ubuntu-16.04

I am working on an **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS** system and I have the following doubt.

Into the **/etc/environment** file I have delcared the following variables:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
http_proxy=http://XX.YYY.ZZ.KK:3128
https_proxy=http://XX.YYY.ZZ.KK:3128
HTTP_PROXY=http://XX.YYY.ZZ.KK:3128
HTTPS_PROXY=http://XX.YYY.ZZ.KK:3128
```

saving the file.

For the proxy variables I put the exact URL of my machine (not localhost).

Then listing the environment variables by the **env** command I obtain the following output:

```
my.user@VHCLWSO2AS02:/etc$ env
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
XDG_SESSION_ID=166339
PWD=/etc
HOME=/home/myuser
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
MAIL=/var/mail/my.user
HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
SHELL=/bin/sh
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=my.user
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1022
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
ftp_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/
```

As you can see the previous 4 proxy environment variables contains the value **127.0.0.1:3128** instead the declared one that uses the proper IP of the machine.

Why? What am I missing? In case how can I refresh these variables without rebooting my system? (I can not perform a reboot of the system)

Comment: You can't reboot but can you log out and back in?

Comment: @Mokubai I tried but I still obtain the same values performing the env command